# Grunt to concatenate angular ui router templates into one file

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, gruntjs

I have an `angular-ui-router` project with 150 files all over the place. I want to write a grunt task to combine all of them into a single `index.html` like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="path-to-file-1.html">   
Content of file-1.html here </script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="path-to-file-2.html">   
Content of file-2.html here </script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="path-to-file-3.html">   
Content of file-3.html here </script>

...
```

I am thinking about using https://github.com/outaTiME/grunt-replace but I want to do this as **DRY** as possible.

My current thinking:

**index.html**

```
<body>
  @@path-to-file-1.html

  @@path-to-file-2.html

  @@path-to-file-3.html
</body>
```

**gruntfile.js**

```
replace: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      patterns: [
        {
          match: 'path-to-file-1.html',
          replacement: '<%= grunt.file.read("path/to/file-1.html.html") %>'
        },
        {
          match: 'path-to-file-2.html',
          replacement: '<%= grunt.file.read("path/to/file-2.html.html") %>'
        },
        {
          match: 'path-to-file-3.html',
          replacement: '<%= grunt.file.read("path/to/file-3.html.html") %>'
        }
      ]
    },
    files: [
      {expand: true, flatten: true, src: ['src/index.html'], dest: 'build/'}
    ]
  }
}
```

This is not **DRY** as I have to repeat the `@@path-to-file-1.html` for 150 times in both files. Is there a way to write it in the index.html only and have grunt task to automatically "imply" that the match string will be the file name (well of course replace `-` with `/` for path)?

**BONUS**: How to scan the directories to get the filenames and concat them in **index.html**? I think this is the best solution so I don't have to maintain new file adding in. Maybe this is another module that I don't know?

Comment: You should write custom grunt task. It's not very difficult. Use `grunt.file.expand` to get array of file names from something like `src: ['app/**/*.html']`. Then loop, and do whatever you need.

Comment: So let say I have `templates: grunt.file.expand({src: 'views/**/*.html']})`, how do I access the `templates` array?

Answer (score 2):

Don't put them in an html file. Use grunt (or more easily gulp) to create a templates.js file which automatically places the html into the template cache.

For example, in my projects I use https://github.com/miickel/gulp-angular-templatecache

```
// create angular template js from html partials
gulp.task('templates', ['clean'], function(){
    var opts = { empty: true, spare: true, quotes: true };
    gulp.src('public/apps/myapp/**/*.html')
        //.pipe(minifyHTML(opts))
        .pipe(templateCache({ root: '/apps/myapp/' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/myapp/js'));
});
```

This will create a js file that contains markup that is placed into the template cache on load.

Comment: I have to use .html file concat because I don't want to depend on the XHR of angular.js. Simple reason: We have people internally just want to double click on index.html and see everything. They are not technical to run on a server (like LiveReload or grunt).

Comment: Well the project I linked to is pretty small. I am sure you could fork it and modify it to make your own gulp process to concat into an html file.

Answer (score 1):

I may be late on this one, but here is another plugin that can help you to merge angular template into a single HTML file :
https://github.com/astik/grunt-angular-combine
Here is an example :

```
grunt.initConfig({
  angularCombine: {
    combine: {
      files : [ {
        cwd : 'app/views',
        src : [ 'module1/foo.html', 'module2/woot.html', 'modules3/*.html' ],
        dest : 'tmp/combined-views.html'
      } ]
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Then do you know how I can use the templates in my one big template file in the ui0router file? How do I reference them?

Comment: To reference the big template file into index.html, you can use your original technic with grunt-replace. This time, no DRY problem as there is only one placeholder :  @@path-to-big-generated-template-file.html.
Process should then be : grunt-angular-combine -> grunt-replace.